# I would like to change a specific rel=canonical url to another one in prestashop

Tags: .htaccess, canonical-link, rel

I would like to **change **a specific rel=canonical url to another one in prestashop. I do not want to **add **but **to change** the existing ones.

for this page
https://site.pl/sklep/
this

change to

and for for this page https://site.pl/sklep/product.html

change to

Php and htaccess add options.

Comment: This has nothing to do with .htaccess. You will have to find the place in the template or the function that outputs this element.

Comment: Well, you _might_ want to implement a redirect from the old to new URL in `.htaccess` (for SEO) if Prestashop is unable to do this? But otherwise, this is a Prestashop thing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.